# Remove duplicate gps coordinates within grouping variable

Tags: r, aggregate, r-sp

I have a data set consisting of the GPS collection localities for many individuals of different species. Specifically my data set has 3 columns: longitude, latitude, and species. I would like to remove duplicate and very similar collection localities within each species, while treating each species independently for this purpose. Working in the R package sp, I am able to do this (while ignoring species) using the following code:

```
    data = read.csv(file="Population_locality.csv", header=T)
    coordinates(data) <- 1:2
    reduced <- remove.duplicates(data, zero = 1, remove.second = TRUE)
```

However, I have been unable to figure out how to remove duplicates within each species, while treating each species independently. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = read.csv(file="Population_locality.csv", header=T)
    coordinates(data) <- 1:2
    splitData <- split(data, data$species)
    newData <- lapply(splitData, remove.duplicates, zero = 1, remove.second = TRUE)
```

Use the split function to divide the species into separate lists. You can then apply your function on each list item. If you need to combine them back together `do.call("rbind", newData)` should work.